# Add facebook/google+/twitter like button

Tags: android

I download some articles from a website and display them in my app.
Each article has has a like button for facebook google+ and twitter and I'd like to keep these buttons in my app.

I though of setting a textview with html text and these button's html/javascript code...could it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I wouldn't expect a simple text view to handle HTML and Javascript. So in your case you should either

1. Implement such buttons yourself, with use of Facebook/google+/twitter API,
2. Or try to use WebView ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html ) - a small browser in your application. It will support html and JS, however, no guarantees that +1 will work, as most probably it requires user to be logged in and have active session, and I'm not sure will WebView share Cookies with other browsers. This way needed to be checked.

However, you can always redirect from this WebView to system browser, and it will process +1 with showing SignIn screen if necessary.

Good luck